# iTextsharp: Add image and text in a loop (IE, Firefox, Chrome)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, loops, text, itext

I have a form with a button that generates a pdf file. The file loops through an array of images and text and insert each image and text on an absolute position of the document. I can add the image, without the text and it works well. I can also add the text without the image and all work well. However, When I add both at the same time, I get the error that

```
there was an error processing the document.
```

Here is the code

```
[HttpPost]
    public FileStreamResult ff(MyModel model)
    {
        MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.SetMargins(50, 25, 25, 30);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream).CloseStream = false;
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream);
        writer.CloseStream = false;
        doc.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        string path = "";
        Image Img;

        int num = 0;
        float imageSize = 160f, margin = 5f, position = 600;
        ColumnText ct;

        foreach (var item in model)
        {

            /*ct = new ColumnText(cb);
            myText = new Phrase(new Chunk(numbering[num] + " " + item.Caption, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 9, Font.ITALIC)));
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, doc.LeftMargin + margin, position + 5f, imageSize, 2, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            ct.Go();
            x += 10;
            y += 12;*/

   /////The code above and the code below(withing the loop) do not work when they are together but work well when they are not together

            path = item.path;
            Img = Image.GetInstance(path);
            Img.ScaleToFit(imageSize, imageSize);
            Img.SetAbsolutePosition(doc.LeftMargin + margin, position);
            Img.Border = Rectangle.TOP_BORDER | Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER | Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER | Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER;
            Img.BorderWidth = 1f;
            doc.Add(Img);


            num++;
            position -= imageSize;
        }

        document.Close();
        byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
        workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
        workStream.Position = 0;

        return new FileStreamResult(workStream, "application/pdf");

    }
```

Internet explorer and firefox display an error `There was an error processing the page. There was an error reading this document(18)`.

Chrome does display the page, but the arrangement of the pictures is wrong. The second picture appears first and the last picture fails to show up, but is border is displayed as the last image(like an empty canvas)

what am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you set the filename of the result?

```
var result = new FileStreamResult(workStream, "application/pdf");
result.FileDownloadName = "test.pdf";
return result;
```